# Query terms modifiedTime or createdTime result in error for Drive.Files.list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Time based query search terms seem to be broken for `Drive.File.list`.

When using the [example query listed in the docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files#examples) below:

`Drive.Files.list({q: "modifiedTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00'"})`

The following error is thrown:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.list failed with error: Invalid query

Am I missing something?  Is there a work around to use modifiedTime and createdTime in queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### About `modifiedDate`

In the current stage, Drive API of Advanced Google services uses Drive API v2. So, in this case, `modifiedTime` is required to be modified to `modifiedDate`. `modifiedTime` is for Drive API v3. So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
Drive.Files.list({ q: "modifiedDate > '2012-06-04T12:00:00'" });
```

- As additional information, if you want to use `modifiedTime`, you can use the following sample script using Drive API v3.

  ```js
  const searchQuery = "modifiedTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00'";
  const url = encodeURI(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=${searchQuery}`);
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
  ```

### About `createdDate`

In the current stage, it seems that `createdDate` of Drive API v2 cannot be used. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79355545) In this case, if you are required to use the search query with Drive API, it is required to use `createdTime` of Drive API v3. [Ref (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/10/19/workaround-createddate-cannot-be-used-with-searchfiles-of-driveapp-in-google-apps-script/) So, the sample script is as follows.

```js
const searchQuery = "createdTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00'";
const url = encodeURI(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=${searchQuery}`);
const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
```

### References:

- [Method: files.list of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/list)
- [Method: files.list of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list)

Comment: ok that fixes the modified search but neither createdDate nor createdTime work.

Comment: @webstermath Thank you for replying. I forgot about `createdDate`. I apologize for this. I added about `createdDate`. Please confirm it.